# VS2017: C++: Iterating Through a const std::map<enum, string>: Link Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, constants, stdmap, const-iterator

I have a link error on the following code.

**header file**

```
    //we have a static class member std::map that I want to be read-only
    //the enums are numeric but not sequential
    typedef std::map<MyEnumType, std::string> MyStdMapType

    class MyClass { static const MyStdMapType myMap; }
```

**source file**

```
    //populate - static var outside of class
    const MyStdMapType MyClass::myMap = { {enumVal1, str1}, ... }
```

**Then, later, I want to iterate through the map**

```
      for (MyStdMapType::const_iterator iter = MyClass::myMap.begin(); iter != MyClass::myMap.end(); iter++)
      {
<stuff>
      }
```

**The "for" line is giving a link error. If I comment the line out, it compiles!:**

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::map<enum MyEnumType,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<enum MyEnumType>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<enum MyEnumType const ,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > const MyClass::myMap" (?myMap@MyClass@@2V?$map@W4MyEnum@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@W4MyEnum@@@3@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBW4MyEnum@@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@3@@std@@B)
```

Comment: Essentially, you need to include `const MyStdMapType myMap;` in a source file (not a header) somewhere.

Comment: Brethren: Points taken - agreed. My apologies.
I've updated the post.

To summarize:
1. typedef defined in header. Static class variable declared in class in header.
2. Relevant class variable defined and initialized in cpp file.

I'm aware [through bitter experience!] of the intricacies of setting up static variables...

Rgds

Steve

Comment: How can this be a duplicate if he is assigning a value to the static variable in a source file?

Comment: More details:

I have other static vars set up, and they work fine.
If I move the iterative code into the same class, it compiles fine.
The problem occurs when I'm accessing the [public static] variable from another class in another cpp, #including the relevant header. 
Rgds
Steve

Comment: I can further confirm that when the static is accessed from within its own class [in the constructor], the iteration works perfectly, and the correct enum key and std::string value pairs are debug printed.

Per @Jerry Jeremiah, is this a duplicate?

Comment: I have voted to reopen this as I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: The user who closed my question as duplicate pointed me to another that does not address my issue.

However, I think it is related to this one:

Accessing a global static variable from another class

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540091/accessing-a-global-static-variable-from-another-class

/Steve